# java 7 - guava - merge list of maps into map

Tags: arrays, data-structures, hashmap, guava, java-7

I am using java 7 for this project and I have list of type `List<Map<String, Object>>` , i want to it merge list of maps into single map, so the output is `Map<String, Object>` with all the entries of the original list.. Is it possible using java 7 or other libraries like guava

Comment: Do you have any particular problem with the implementation? Simple for-each loop and putting all entries to new map should work, I don't think there's more elegant solution on Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to do this by simply iterating over the maps and copy all of their mappings into a new map:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> merge(Iterable<? extends Map<K, V>> maps) {
    Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map<K, V> map : maps) {
        result.putAll(map);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<String, Object> mergedMap = merge(maps);
```